# how to merge two collections results into a single result in Mongodb with NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

If I have:

```
**Collection1**
{
  id: 01
  name: John
  year: 2022
},
{
  id: 02
  name: Smith
  year: 2022
}

**Collection2**
{
  id: 03
  name: Mathias
  year: 2022
},
{
  id: 04
  name: Carl
  year: 2022
}
```

How is the best way to get a result like that in mongo without create a new collection??

```
**output**:
{
  id: 01
  name: John
  year: 2022
},
{
  id: 02
  name: Smith
  year: 2022
},
{
  id: 03
  name: Mathias
  year: 2022
},
{
  id: 04
  name: Carl
  year: 2022
2
```

I tried with **lookup ** but the result was always a Sub-Array, I want an array like a join in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is not a relational database, but you can perform a left outer join by using the `$lookup` stage. The `$lookup` stage lets you specify which collection you want to join with the current collection, and which fields should match.You can use $lookup to create a view over two collections and then run queries against the view.

Or a basic approach could be like this

```
[collectionOne, collectionTwo] = await Promise.all([await db.collectionOne.find({}), await db.collectionTwo.find({})])
```

You can later on flatten the subarrays using `flat()`method
[Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)